# Integrate $2^{x^2}$

Tags: integration

Can someone please show me the integral $\int 2^{x^2}dx$?

I know that the integral of a constant $b^x$ would result to $$\frac{b^x}{\ln b}$$, so would that mean that the function be $2^{x^x}$ and that the integral would be $\frac{(2^{x^2})}{\ln 2^x}$ ?

Comment: Can't be done in closed form.

Comment: i'm sorry, closed form? what is that?

Comment: I will assume your function is $2^{x^2}$. The antiderivative of this function cannot be expressed in terms of "elementary" functions, that is, the functions on the calculator keyboard, combined using the arithmetic operations and function composition.

Comment: It means "there's no nice function like $f(x) = x^2/2^x$ whose derivative is your function. "Nice" here means "using polynomials, roots, trig functions, log, exp."

Comment: so how would i answer this? huhuhuhu

Comment: It's well known that there is no closed form for the indefinite integral of $e^{x^2}$ (though I think the proof is not well known), but there are closed forms for the definite integral over all reals.  This may also be the case with your problem.

Comment: @madison This is most likely an [X Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/201314).  You *think* you need to solve problem X (that is, compute $\int 2^{x^2}\;dx$) to solve the bigger problem Y (wherever you found this integral).  However, you (most likely) *don't have to* find the primitive of $2^{x^2}$ to solve your real problem.

Comment: I'm guessing this problem asks to find the derivative of that thing using the FTOC. A lot of people are tricked into attempting the integral.

Comment: See [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm). Also, $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty2^{-x^2}~dx=2~\int_0^\infty2^{-x^2}~dx=\sqrt{\frac\pi{\ln2}}$.

Answer (score 4):

$2^{x^2} = e^{c x^2}$ where $c = \ln(2)$, so
$$\int 2^{x^2}\; dx = \int \exp(cx^2)\; dx = \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{c}} \text{erfi}(\sqrt{c} x)$$
where $\text{erfi}$ is the "[imaginary error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html)".
This is not an elementary function, but it is a perfectly good [special function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_functions).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that this question is a rephrasing of a textbook question that said something like "Find a function whose derivative is $2^{x^2}$. If that's the case, then you could say that
$$
g(x) = \int_0^x 2^{t^2} ~dt
$$
is such a function; it's well-defined and differentiable (with the correct derivative) because of the fundamental theorem(s) of calculus.